# Предварительная загрузка изображений

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать предварительная загрузка изображений без массива? Т.к. изображений много и каждый путь прогонять через массив трудоёмко. Что-то подобное будет корректным?

```js
  $('.wrapper img').each(function(){
        var att =$(this).attr('src');
        var qwe = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
        att=att.replace(qwe,'_q.jpg');
        
        var newI= $('<img src="'+att+'">');
        
        $(this).click(function(){ 
          
        $('.light img').attr('src',att);
    });
```

Comment: Есть `document.images` там доступ ко всем изображениям.

Comment: @nick_n_a 3 Изначально пути к картинкам нигде не "светятся" - не известны.